# how do I make the json file record my data permanently?

Tags: python-3.x

Each time I run the code the data overwrites the contents of `signupdatabase.json`.

How can I avoid overwriting the existing file contents?

```
import json

with open('signupdatabase.json','w') as f:
    json.dump('b',f)
    json.dump('a',f)


print('good')
```

Comment: That code will not erase the file on close. I added `print(open('signupdatabase.json').read())` and got `"a""b"`. It does have a problem - since you don't put a delimiter such as `\n` between the json objects, you may have problems decoding them later.

Comment: If you run the script multiple times, it will overwrite the existing stuff because you open in "w" mode, which truncates the file. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yeap I noticed it overwrite existing data, so how do I overcome this problem? Thanks for the help anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options. You can store username/password in a single `dict` that you load from the file when the program starts and save when its been updated. Encrypting the password is a good idea, but beyond this question.

```
import json
import os
import getpass

db_filename = 'signupdatabase.json'

# create on first use
if not os.path.exists(db_filename):
    with open(db_filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump({}. f)

# open database
with open(db_filename) as f:
    db = json.load(f)

user = input("User Name: ")
pw = getpass.getpass()

db[user] = pw

# save database
with open(db_filename, 'a') as f:
    db = json.dump(db, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the file in `append` mode, and add `'\n'` after every line.

   ```
   with open('signupdatabase.json','a') as f:
       json.dump('b\n',f)
       json.dump('a\n',f)
   ```
2. Don't use a JSON file as a database.
3. Don't ever save passwords in plain text, not even in a "proper" database.